# React passing props

Tags: reactjs

```
const App = () = {
 return(
  <Article 
    render={
      (getContextProps) => (
      <Context {...getContextProps()}>{sometext}</Context>
    )}
  />
 )
}
```

Hi Everyone, recently I came cross this piece of code, function component in react, in the render attribute I passed in, which has `getContextProps` as a variable, i am confused about what is `{...getContextProps()}` means, my understand is that need to pass `getContextProps` as props to the child Context component as attribute using rest operator, but I don't know why the syntax is `{...getContextProps()}` so its a variable or its a function? is that some particular syntax for React?

Comment: Does your code work?
Could you share your whole App.js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above case is an example of using [`JSX spread attributes syntax`](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/07bbe37bc42b6d4aef81) to pass on dynamic pops to the Context component.

A simplified version of the above code would be

```
const App = () = {
 return(
  <Article 
    render={
      (getContextProps) => {
      const props = getContextProps();
     (
      <Context {...props}>{sometext}</Context>
    )}}
  />
 )
}
```

Now in tha above code, `getContextProps` would return an object that you would spread an pass as props to the `Context` component